# Dynamic Linq Query between dates

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to use [Dynamic Linq Query](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) to create a function that will compare a field between 2 dates.
The function looks like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> BetweenDates<T>(this IQueryable<T> models, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string propertyName)
{
    var start = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, startDate.Day, 0, 0, 1); // Set to 1 second past midnight
    var end = new DateTime(endDate.Year, endDate.Month, endDate.Day, 0, 0, 0); // Set to midnight

    return models.Where($"{ propertyName } => { start } && { propertyName } <= { end }");
}
```

If I run this, I get an error:

> Expression expected

but I can't figure out what is wrong.
Has anyone done this before?

Comment: I don't know if it will fix your problem, but you've got your "Is Greater Than" syntax wrong, it should be `{ propertyName } >= { start } …`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't recall the format of `DateTime` literals in Dynamic LINQ string expressions (apparently just including their string representation as in your attempt is not enough), but you can pass parameters through the additional `params object[] values` argument and refer to them inside the string by position as `@0`, `@1`, `@2` etc:

```
return models.Where($"{propertyName} >= @0 && {propertyName} <= @1", start, end);
```

This will bind `start` and `end` as constant values in the generated query.

If you want them to become parameters, then use anonymous type (explicit closure) like this:

```
return models.Where($"{propertyName} >= @0.start && {propertyName} <= @0.end", new { start, end });
```

Comment: although that seems to be better (I don't get an error) it does seem to format it incorrectly thus returning no results. It get's converted to this: `convert(datetime2, '2017-06-21 00:00:00.0000000', 121)` which is not what I want (I guess)

Comment: Well, this is exactly the same if you bind constants to your query. Are you looking for parametrized query?

Comment: I think it works, I will do some more testing, something strange is happening before it get's to the client which might not be connected